# Not able to run an app on Android

Tags: java, android

I am parsing Json data from a URL in Android. I am not getting any error while executing. But nothing is coming up.

Here is my MainActivity.Java code:

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
 this.fetchTwitterPublicTimeline()));

}

public ArrayList<String> fetchTwitterPublicTimeline()

{

    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        URL twitter = new URL(

                "http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json");

        URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

                tc.getInputStream()));

        String line;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);

                listItems.add(jo.getString("text"));

            }

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return listItems;

}

}
```

And this is my manifest.xml content:

```
  package="com.example.harsh"

  android:versionCode="1"

  android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

 <application

    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"

              android:label="Android List View">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>



</application>
```

This is the R.java file:

```
package com.example.harsh;

public final class R {


public static final class attr {

}

public static final class dimen {

public static final int activity_horizontal_margin=0x7f040000;


  public static final int activity_vertical_margin=0x7f040001;

}

public static final class drawable {

    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;

}

public static final class id {

    public static final int action_settings=0x7f080000;

}

public static final class layout {

    public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;

}

public static final class menu {

    public static final int main=0x7f070000;

}

public static final class string {

    public static final int action_settings=0x7f050001;

    public static final int app_name=0x7f050000;

    public static final int hello_world=0x7f050002;

}

public static final class style {public static final int 
 activity_horizontal_margin=0x7f040000;

    public static final int activity_vertical_margin=0x7f040001;

}

public static final class drawable {

    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;

}

public static final class id {

    public static final int action_settings=0x7f080000;

}

public static final class layout {

    public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;

}

public static final class menu {

    public static final int main=0x7f070000;

}

public static final class string {

    public static final int action_settings=0x7f050001;

    public static final int app_name=0x7f050000;

    public static final int hello_world=0x7f050002;

}

public static final class style {

public static final int AppBaseTheme=0x7f060000;

    public static final int AppTheme=0x7f060001;
}
}
```

While running it nothing is coming up after this:

```
[2013-10-15 23:37:39 - FirstApp] adb is running normally.

[2013-10-15 23:37:39 - FirstApp] Performing com.example.harsh.MainActivity activity launch

[2013-10-15 23:37:40 - FirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'abc'

[2013-10-15 23:37:40 - FirstApp] Uploading FirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

[2013-10-15 23:37:46 - FirstApp] Installing FirstApp.apk...

[2013-10-15 23:38:26 - FirstApp] Success!
```

So i am not able to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Have you checked the log (LogCat)?

Comment: Have you tried logging out the lines you are getting back from the HTTP request? Personally, when I paste that URL into a browser, I get this for example: {"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]} . If that's what your code is getting, it makes sense your JSON parsing code doesn't find any rows.

Comment: It is sending signal in Logcat.
Now i am getting this :

[2013-10-15 23:58:50 - FirstApp] Failed to install FirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2013-10-15 23:58:50 - FirstApp] (null)
[2013-10-15 23:58:51 - FirstApp] Launch canceled!

Comment: Here, add this after your while statement: Log.d("MyApp", "Received string: " + line); . Then see what the server is sending you. The console message you are talking about is meaningless, you hit cancel or something when launching or it timed out trying to install the app, etc.. Just run it again.

Comment: In logcat under verbose i am getting this: Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're doing network/internet access on the main UI thread by calling your fetchTwitterPublicTimeline method in the activities onCreate. This will throw an exception in API levels newer than Honeycomb.

You should move that to an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or background thread that is kicked off in the onCreate method and then fill your adapter when the AsyncTask completes and has data.

Comment: I have given the internet permission in manifest file. You can check above in the code mentioned.

Comment: @user861938  You missed the point.  It does not matter what permissions you have, you cannot do network IO on the UI thread.  Please read the answer again.

Comment: @user861938 after posting my answer I saw your manifest permissions and edited to remove the internet permission comment. thanks.

Comment: @PatrickKafka Now i am getting failed to install .apk on the emulator. Is it because of the reason you mentioned?

Comment: Can you tell me about that?

Comment: I'm not sure about the fail installing the apk. It sounds like it's not related to this issue you were having. You can try commenting all of your onCreate code so it's essentially doing nothing and see if the install succeeds... Also, sometimes the emulators just get out of whack and just need to be restarted or recreated.